# Using jQuery or Javascript - target an image, then set it as a background image for a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I had an idea today, and I was wondering if it was possible to do, and if I could get any pointers on how to accomplish it.

I own an e commerce website that dynamically loads a product's image upon page load. Here's the basic html structure for the image when it is loaded on the page:

```
<div id="container">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a id="product_photo_zoom_url" herf="#">
            <img id="product_photo" />
        </a>
    </td>
</table>
</tr>
</div>
```

My idea is this:
I would like to use a script to target the image #product_photo. This script would then set that targeted image as a background image for the div #container.

I would then need to be able to set the following css for that dynamically added background image within the div #container in the script as well:

```
#container {background-size: 100% auto; background-position: center top; opacity: 0.1;}
```

Hopefully that made sense. Is this at all possible?

Thanks guys - Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = $("#product_phoro").attr('src');
$("#container").css('background-image', image);
```

Comment: Good answer. It ignores the questioner's request to set the other CSS properties he lists, but there's really no reason to use JQuery for that, since you know what it's going to be. But you could do so with the same method as in line 2 above.

Comment: I assumed those other properties would be set statically in the CSS as shown, he only needs to use JS to vary the image.